# NextJS Property 'Component' does not exist on type 'App<{}, {}, {}>'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I'm using NextJS with Typescript and when I try to build the code I get the following error in the _app.tsx file:

> Property 'Component' does not exist on type 'App<{}, {}, {}>'.

I get Component from AppProps type ('next/app'), this is the code:

```
import React from "react";
import { CssBaseline } from "@material-ui/core";
import { ThemeProvider } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import theme from "../themes";
import AppProps from "next/app";

export default function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <CssBaseline />
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Looking at the Typescript docs you should be destructuring `AppProps` when importing: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/typescript#custom-app

Comment: That was it, at the end it was an easy fix. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AppProps should been impoted from "next/app" as a normal export, not as a default one. Here is an example of it:

```
import '../styles/globals.css';
import { AppProps } from 'next/app';

function MyApp( { Component, pageProps }: AppProps ) {
    return <Component {...pageProps} />;
}
```

Note the "{ }" symbols around AppProps import.

Hope this helps you!